# How to determine if any network connection is established, not an internet connection

Tags: c#, networking

I'm writing a C# program at work and I need to determine if a connection to the network has been established. I've searched and searched and found that there are tons of posts here about internet connections, but very little about detecting just a network connection. I don't have very much code, all I have is this:

```
NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
                    foreach (NetworkInterface Interface in interfaces)
                    {
                        //some testing criteria goes here
                    }
```

but I'm not sure if this applies to just network connections or not what properties and values to look for for network connections. Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check the configured IP on the NIC is a non internet routable address. That is to say it is configured using a class A, B or C network.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

These addresses cannot be used on the internet and only serve local networks.

Comment: What if the IP is static?  That doesn't prove that there's currently a network connection.  The cable could be unplugged.

Comment: You can use windows WMI to determine the status of the network connecton. Or I believe there are application events in .NET that can detect this sort of thing

Comment: the wikipedia article did help me out I think Ross. Just want to make sure that I'm understanding it right: if I get the IP address that's been assigned and it starts with10..., 172.16.. or 192.168... then that means it's a Private IP address meaning that it was assigned for a local network? I think that's how it goes, in researching this i've found out that when I log in from work my IP address always begins with 10...

Comment: Thats correct. These address only exist in local networks. Public addresses are NAT'd over to these addresses.